# Saving MATLAB graphs in a specific resolution

Tags: matlab

How do I change the resolution of my MATLAB graphs? The default seems to be 96x96 [PPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can save using the `print` command; here's how:

```
h1=figure;
your plotting commands here

print(h1,'-djpeg','-r150','filename')
```

The `-r150` argument sets the resolution to 150 DPI. you can set it higher or lower depending on your need. This is assuming you're saving as a JPEG. If not, there are other options such as `-dpng` for PNG, `-dbmp` for 24-bit bitmap, etc. more can be found in the help section for `print`.

That said, if your plot consists only of lines, I would recommend using `-depsc` which saves it as an EPS file, which is scalable and lossless. You also won't have to define a resolution, so you can simply do

`print(h1,'-depsc','filename')`

You can convert this EPS file to PDF and retain the same resolution, yet have portability between applications and platforms. I wouldn't recommend saving to PDF directly as MATLAB puts additional white spaces around the plot, wheras the EPS bounding box is tight, and looks neat.

Comment: Something like this gives reasonable results to save the current (i.e. last clicked) figure: `print(gcf, '-dpng', '-r600', 'filename.png')`

Answer (score 3):

Changing a Figure's Settings: [Setting the resolution](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f3-84337.html#f3-99727)

Comment: That reference says that the only way to set the resolution is through the `print` command.

Comment: StackOverflow's avoid-just-putting-a-link policy is sensible normally, but doubly so this time, because the link can't be accessed without registering for a TheMathWorks account!