# Increase matlab figure resolution, when saving in headless mode

Tags: matlab

I have a plot, which I want to save with a bigger resolution. But the documentation states that Matlab ignores '-r' option to `print` command, when running in a headless mode. Is there some other way to increase printed figure resolution?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Saving MATLAB graphs in a specific resolution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212573/saving-matlab-graphs-in-a-specific-resolution

Comment: @Ghaul - the problem is, that question's solution does not work in headless mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the function `export_fig` written by Oliver Woodford. Its `-r` option (resolution) also works in headless mode. The function is available [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629).

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above, export_fig provides a solution, but in later versions of Matlab, it may take a fair amount of tinkering to get it working.

```
export_fig(gcf, 'figure.png', '-png','-painters','-m2');
```

Should do the trick. The critical parameters here are:

'-painters' which forces matlab to use the correct rendering engine. The default (OpenGL) does not work in -nodisplay mode and "zbuffer" is no longer supported in recent version of matlab.

'-m2' which indicates output at x2 resolution. You can obviously specify '-m3' for x3 resolution and so on.